# Changing text on selection in Text widget Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

How would i go about implementing something like this to the `Text` widget in Tkinter?

What i want to do is have a `Text` widget display text, however when a user clicks it and the widget is in focus, the text goes away?

for instance, text box before click:

```
[...]
```

text widget after click and in focus:

```
[]
```

if nothing was entered and widget out of focus:

```
[...]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add a binding for a button click (`<1>`), and in the handler for that event you delete the text. Then, add a binding for when the widget loses focus (`<Leave>`) to insert "..." if the widget is empty.